# Como verificar se a url é verdadeira

Tags: javascript, url

Fiz esse código simples para codificar urls, mas gostaria de que ele funcionasse apenas com url verificando se o protocolo e o hostname estão corretos ou se o link magnético está correto:

```
http://www.exemplo.com/
https://www.exemplo.com/
http://exemplo.com/
https://exemplo.com/
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:  //url magnético
```

```js
function codificar() {
    var valor = document.getElementById("teste").value;
    var encode = window.btoa(valor);
    
    document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = encode;
}
```

```html
<p>Clique no botão para codificar a url.</p>
<br>
<input style='width:152px;' type="text" id="teste" value="http://www.exemplo.com">
<button onclick="codificar()">CODIFICAR</button>
<br>
<br>
<textarea style='width:150px; resize: none;' id="saida"></textarea>
```

Comment: Você quer verificar se as `url` possuem os padrões que você citou?

Comment: Sim exatamente isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode estar verificando se suas strings pertencem a um padrão utilizando `regex`. Segue um exemplo de uma `er` (expressão regular) e como ficaria seu uso:

```
  var re = new RegExp("^((http(s?):\/\/(www.)?[a-z]+.com\/)|(magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:))")

  var term = "http://www.exemplo.com/"

  if (re.test(term)) {
    alert("Valid");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid");
  }
```

Da forma que essa `er` foi construida, ela irá aceitar qualquer `string` que comece com esses padrões:

```
http://www.exemplo.com/
https://www.exemplo.com/
http://exemplo.com/
https://exemplo.com/
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:
```

Ou seja, se tiver esse padrão no inicio da `string`, qualquer coisa que estiver depois do `.com/` nos casos da `url` e de `btih:` no caso do `magnet link`, ele irá aceitar. Como por exemplo:

```
http://www.exemplo.com/qualquercoisaaquiassim/?-thiagorespondeu
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar esse código completo abaixo caso precise de `.net` `.org` `.xyz` etc.. e está funcionando perfeitamente com o url magnético. Ele vai verificar a expressão, caso seja inválida irá retornar uma alerta.
Caso precise adicionar `ftp` adicione aqui `(ftp|http|https)`, o "`|` ou `||`" é o operador logico correspondente a `ou`.

```js
function codificar() {
 var reg = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?|magnet:\?xt=urn:btih:/
 var valor = document.getElementById("teste").value;
 var encode = window.btoa(valor);

 if (reg.test(valor)) {
  document.getElementById("saida").innerHTML = encode;
 } else {
  alert("Url Invalido");
 }
}
```

```html
<p>Clique no botão para codificar a url.</p>
<br>
<input style='width:152px;' type="text" id="teste" value="http://www.exemplo.com">
<button onclick="codificar()">CODIFICAR</button>
<br>
<textarea style='width:150px; resize: none;' id="saida"></textarea>
```